# Appending json data to listview c#

Tags: c#, json, winforms, listview

I am new to c# and would like to add the following data to a listview
http://live.glidernet.org/flightlog/index.php?a=EHDL&s=QFE&u=M&z=2&p=&d=30052015&j
I want to create a listview item foreach flight, I managed to add a subitem by the following code.

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("Foo bar");
lvi.SubItems.Add("Foo bar");
lvi.SubItems.Add("Foo bar");
FlarmListView.Items.Add(lvi);
```

How can I parse the JSON data to this listview?

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), you could do something like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string json = client.DownloadString("http://live.glidernet.org/flightlog/index.php?a=EHDL&s=QFE&u=M&z=2&p=&d=30052015&j");

JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);

// create an array of ListViewItems from the JSON
var items = data["flights"]
    .Children<JObject>()
    .Select(jo => new ListViewItem(new string[] 
    {
        (string)jo["glider"],
        (string)jo["takeoff"],
        (string)jo["glider_landing"],
        (string)jo["glider_time"]
    }))
    .ToArray();

FlarmListView.View = View.Details;
FlarmListView.FullRowSelect = true;
FlarmListView.Columns.Add("Glider ID", 70);
FlarmListView.Columns.Add("Takeoff Time", 85);
FlarmListView.Columns.Add("Landing Time", 85);
FlarmListView.Columns.Add("Time In Air", 85);
FlarmListView.Items.AddRange(items);
```

Comment: Thanks Perfect Answer But what if we have a JSON structured like this  `{
  "data": {
    "day1": {
      "mId": "XgzhugCNT",
      "pageId": "2",
      "votes": "2,063",
      "language": "English"
    },
    "day2": {
      "mId": "9ilrMdX15S",
      "pageId": "10",
      "votes": "2,893",
      "language": "French"
    },
    "day3": {
      "mId": "9ilert415S",
      "pageId": "8",
      "votes": "2,343",
      "language": "English"
    }
  }
}` @brain-rogers

Comment: @SerenityEmmanuel See fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xcIBt7

Comment: Thanks alot really appreciate