# How to get data from a nested json in c#

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, winforms

`{"data": {"day2": {"mId": "9ilrMdX15S", "votes": "2,893"},"day3": {"mId": "9ilert415S","votes": "2,343"}}}` 
How can i retrieve the data from a json data as such (i.e the data in "day2", or "day3") i followed the answers here > [Appending json data to listview c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401704/appending-json-data-to-listview-c-sharp/32469136#comment120325607_32469136) by Brain Rogers but the answer only work for json object not for nested json.

Comment: Its not really nested I think. You could see this as a class with a single array/list containing 'day' objects that have their own properties.

Comment: I think the issue is solved when the days are not written as day1, day2, day3 but an array where a day could have an explicit index.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk I fully overlooked that detail you're correct

Comment: Will it carry on to infinite number of dayX properties? Can you influence the structure of the Json or are you stuck with it?

Comment: i am inputting the day2, day3, objects manually so i basically want to retrieve the data of "data>day2> {all the data inside day2}" only or the data inside day3

Comment: I think it is also interesting to know how you would deal with this object in C# code when it is turned into an object. Would you still be working with day1, day2, dayN then? As you could already `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString)` with Newtonsoft and have a `dynamic` C# object where calling Day1, Day2, DayN already works. But I would definitely try to get it into an array and have  a strong typed object instead of a dynamic.

Comment: `var days = JObject.Parse(json)["data"].ToObject<Dictionary<string, JObject>>();`. Or, build a class object that describes the `DayX` content (it's always the same) and deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, [Your class]>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the response, i was able to solve the task using the SimpleJSON library by Bunny83 [GitHub - Bunny83/SimpleJSON: A simple JSON parser in C#](https://github.com/Bunny83/SimpleJSON)

```
        JSONNode data = JSON.Parse(//jsonData or Url//);
        string mId = data["data"]["day2"]["mId"].Value;
        string votes = data["data"]["day2"]["votes"].Value;
```

Comment: Hi, @ Serenity Emmanuel. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to navigate it:

```
foreach (JProperty day in JObject.Parse(json)["data"])
{
    string name = day.Name;
    string id = day.Value.Value<string>("mId");
    string votes = day.Value.Value<string>("votes");
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this only retrieve the first value that is day2. How do i retrieve the data for day3 only

Answer (score 0):

If you're on .NET 6+, you don't need an external library. Just add this namespace:

```
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;
```

Then you can do this:

```
string jsonInput = "{\"data\": {\"day2\": {\"mId\": \"9ilrMdX15S\", \"votes\": \"2,893\"},\"day3\": {\"mId\": \"9ilert415S\",\"votes\": \"2,343\"}}}";
JsonObject? jsonObject = JsonNode.Parse(jsonInput)?.AsObject();

string? votes = (string?)jsonObject?["data"]?["day2"]?["votes"];  // outputs 2,893
```